# Reading files from within a .tgz folder on the fly

Tags: java, gzip, tar, apache-commons, compression

I am trying to read in a set of .xml documents that are stored inside a .tgz directory on the fly. The structure of the .tgz file is a top level folder 01 with subdirectories A1,A2, etc, and in each of these Ax directories are a set of .xml documents that I wish to read. eg. 01/A1/1234.xml

So far, I can unzip the .tgz folder and reveal the underlying top-level folder but it is considered empty or not recognised as a folder when it should contain several subdirectories that each have a set of .xml documents inside.

```
if (filename.endsWith(".tgz")) {
    TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
    TarArchiveEntry currentEntry = tarInput.getNextTarEntry();

    for(File F : currentEntry.getFile().listFiles())
        System.out.println(F.getName());
}
```

When this block is run, a null pointer exception is thrown when the folder is manipulated. If i run `currentEntry.isDirectory()` it returns true. If I instead run:

```
if (filename.endsWith(".tgz")) {
    TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
    TarArchiveEntry currentEntry = tarInput.getNextTarEntry();
    System.out.println(currentEntry.getDirectoryEntries().length);

    for(TarArchiveEntry F : currentEntry.getDirectoryEntries())
        System.out.println(F.getName());
}
```

The `System.out.println(currentEntry.getDirectoryEntries().length);` line prints 0 when it should be 100. When using either method to loop thru the files in currentEntry, nothing is found.

Is it possible to read the files that should be in this .tgz folder without decompressing it fully, manipulating the files then removing the files manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `getFile` and `getDirectoryEntries` only work if you have created the `TarArchiveEntry` from an actual `File` on your disk in order to write them to an archive. They don't provide anything useful for entries read from an archive.

TAR archives do not offer random access, all you can do is loop through all entries with `getNextTarEntry` and handle those entries you are interested in (stopping when `getNextTarEntry` returns `null`).

Answer (score 1):

You have this problem because you are closing `br`. The `BufferedReader.close()` method closes the underlying stream - the `TarArchiveInputStream` in this case. You should avoid calling `br.close()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was one issue I was having but wasn't the core problem. I have updated the question to focus on the main issue.